# Funny result with multiple backup tape

Tags: tar

I'm testing for lto6 tar encrypted backup

I'm using one G only for the test

```
  tar cMpf - --tape-length=1G --blocking-factor 4096 -X /etc/file.exclude  /| openssl enc -e -aes256 -salt -pass file:unixpass -out /dev/st0
```

The first tape work fine

Ask me for second..I insert press return and...

display content of a file!

```
"<custom_item>type           : SQL_POLICYdescription    : "2.11 sqlnet.ora settings - 'Setting for the remote_os_authent parameter'""....
```

this for thousand of lines,like cat command

Using a file for testing it cat /opt/nessus...

```
opt/nessus/var/nessus/audits/audit_warehouse.audit01402604000014563
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: must insert tape name,i though was automatic generated